# Repair Leaking Roof/Chimney In Winter

Tags: leak, roof, waterproofing, plaster, chimney

I live in an 100 year old house in Michigan.  I have suspicions that the flashing around my chimney is leaking as the plaster in the ceiling directly below the chimney & roof point is getting soft and the paint is peeling.  I intend on doing it the right way and replacing the flashing and/or ensure the seal is in good shape.  The problem is that its winter and I cannot safely get up onto the roof to do that.  Are there products that I could apply from the attic to help block the water from coming in until I can fix this the proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That would be like sealing the bottom side of a sponge--moisture will travel through it to emerge in other areas.

You can probably accomplish the repair even in winter. A water hose will quickly melt snow and ice from the areas you need to access, or use scaffolding and other hardware to work over it.

Comment: Okay I checked the weather and this weekend its supposed to be above freezing and their isnt any ice or snow up there right now.  I am thinking of using this sealant on the flashing.  Have you any experience with products such as these and do you think it would suffice? https://www.homedepot.com/p/Henry-0-90-Gal-208R-Rubber-Wet-Patch-Roof-Cement-HE208R142

Comment: There are products designed to be installed in the wet. Talk to your local contractor supply shop or read labels. I won't have a specific recommendation.